# Cast Anonymous (Any) object to class object in kotlin

Tags: class, object, kotlin, casting

Kotlin compiler is giving me error while running below :

```
fun main() {
    val x = object {
        val i = 1
        val k = "s"
    }
    val y = x as Planet
    if (y is Planet) {
        println("Hello " + x.i)
    }
}


data class Planet(
        var i : Int,
        var k : String
)
```

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
> FileKt$main$x$1 cannot be cast to Planet  at FileKt.main (File.kt:7)
> at FileKt.main (File.kt:-1)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
> (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)

I am unable to understand why i am not able to cast Any object type to specific class object.
Isn't all Kotlin classes inherit from Any super class?

please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: whats up with downvote and no explanation ?

Comment: @Selvin sure but the animal 'could' be a dog? how do i make compiler know it is a dog ?

Answer (score 11):

> Kotlin is a strongly statically typed language. Every variable and every expression has a type that is known at compile time.

In your example you are not specifying the type, but that does not mean it is unknown at compile time.
Kotlin uses type inference to determine its type. In your case `Any`.

```kotlin
val x: Any = object {
    // ...
}
```

[Any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) is the root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has `Any` as a superclass.
This is the reason why you can not cast `Any` to `Planet` at runtime.

What you could do is using Kotlin safe-cast `as?` which returns null instead of an exception:

```kotlin
val planet: Planet? = x as? Planet
```

What you also can do, if you ever casted a Planet to Any, you can cast it back to Planet.

```kotlin
data class Planet(val name: String)
    
val pluto: Planet = Planet("Pluto")
val anyPlanet: Any = pluto
val planet: Planet = anyPlanet as Pluto
```

Comment: this does make the code cast safe but still have to deal with a null object, i have done Class to Any conversion and type checked same in many of my implementations. But here in my unique case i have to accept that explicit anonymous object and also convert or map it with type safety, thank you!

Comment: dont do the casting (other as User) other.login. dont want to add another variable